# How to upload images from React Native App directly to Cloudinary using Attachinary in a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, cloudinary

I'm trying to send a file from a mobile photo library to a Rails API and then upload it to Cloudinary using Attachinary and I'm getting the following error while doing so:

> Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   file:///Users/hugoh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7270BD44-FFEC-423B-8859-933B9A3FD396/data/Containers/Data/Application/9BD2CA62-FDE5-4142-BA25-9DB3713123D6/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Ftestapp-react-native-e2f12178-7fc9-4a5d-810c-c446c8edd435/ImagePicker/9297C84C-F7B5-49AF-93F3-5A080FCFF4C2.jpg:

I'm uploading the image to Cloudinary with the following code in my Rail Api app:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image])
```

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cloudinary+no+such+file+or+directory+%40+rbsysopen&atb=v52-6_b&ia=qa

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to your image is built incorrectly. Please try excluding the file:// for the path-

Users/hugoh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7270BD44-FFEC-423B-8859-933B9A3FD396/data/Containers/Data/Application/9BD2CA62-FDE5-4142-BA25-9DB3713123D6/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Ftestapp-react-native-e2f12178-7fc9-4a5d-810c-c446c8edd435/ImagePicker/9297C84C-F7B5-49AF-93F3-5A080FCFF4C2.jpg:

Comment: This does not work, I'm still getting the same error.